# Knex with PG Client error while migrating

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

i am new to the Knex here is my code for environment unable to migrate in can someone explain the reason of error

```
development: {
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    port: 8889,
    database: 'tuitionBuzz'
  },
  pool: {
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
  },
  acquireConnectionTimeout: 10000,
  migrations: {
    directory: __dirname + '/db/migrations',
  },
  seeds: {
    directory: __dirname + '/db/seeds',
  },
}
```

getting error while Migrating in

```
npx knex migrate:rollback
Using environment: development
/Users/mohdmaroof/Desktop/tuitionBuzz Node.js web/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121
      var eventName = msg.name === 'error' ? 'errorMessage' : msg.name
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/mohdmaroof/Desktop/tuitionBuzz Node.js web/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:27)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:283:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:219:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:638:20)
```

Comment: After editing your question I've noticed that you've missed comma after `pool` option. It is unlikely that this error is related to this typo. But I'm not sure it might be

Comment: It is not working this error is not related to this typo.